# adding && \ to each line on a text file except last line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to add `&& \` on end of each line on a text file except the last line.

Sample input:

```
ps 
mkdir repo 
cd repo/ 
touch file1.txt
```

Expected output:

```
ps && \
mkdir repo && \
cd repo/ && \
touch file1.txt
```

### First attempt

I tried this, but it outputs `&& \` on each line *including the final line*:

```
awk '{print $0"&& \\"}' RS="\r*\n\r*"
```

### Second attempt

I tried using sed:

```
sed '1s/^//;$!s/$/"&&" \\/;$s/$//'
```

This seems to add extra newlines:

```
 ps
 && \
mkdir repo
 && \
cd repo/
 && \
touch file1.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown us your efforts in form of code. Please do add samples of input and expected output too in your question and let us in s then

Comment: You don't need a backslash after `&&`. But sounds like you want to discover `bash -e` for running the script instead.

Comment: Did you want to modify the file itself?

Comment: If the file is intended to be a shell script, you don't need a ``\ `` at end of line immediately after `&&`.  Also, you might try a different approach (if it's a complete script) - set the `-e` flag of the shell to exit after the first failing command.  You could do that by executing using `sh -e`, or you could prepend `set -e` at the start of the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `sed` for something that simple:

```
printf "line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n" | sed '$ ! s/$/ \&\& \\ /'
```

**Output**

```
line 1 && \ 
Line 2 && \ 
Line 3
```

Comment: it wont work properly for me due to conversion i  believe . Trying to run windows txt file in linux . when i ran your code it was like (number indicates lines) 1 : Line 1; 2 : && \ ; 3: Line 2 ; 4: && \ ; and more ... is there a way to avoid sed adding new line ?

Comment: Ugh! `awk` and `sed` are not great bed-mates of Windows files. I'll leave my answer for Linux users, but maybe consider using Windows tools if that's what floats your boat.

Comment: yea been stuck for a long time ha . awk did a job but added && \ at end lol .

Comment: Shouldn't there be no blank at the end, after ``\``?